# Reduce the decision time using video stream [affdex]

Tags: affdex-sdk

As you guys might know, some detections take time using Affectiva SDK (linux in my case). For example, the gender recognition might take around 2-3 secs to output a result, and this is correct and it's the expected behavior, just like affectiva mentions:

> The ROC score of the classifier is 0.95 and the average length of time taken to reach a decision is 3.4 seconds

So, I was wondering if its possible to reduce this time somehow in the SDK. I understand that this could generate a lot of false positives, but I'm testing an scenario where faces disappear quite quickly. If this is not possible, I might have to change to photo analysis instead...

best!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no way to tune gender detection times with video feeds. The only way to reduce your detection time is to use the Photo Detector:
http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_2/cpp/analyze-photo/